# Script for Enigma to cast Midnight Pulse then ULT after blink?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Is it possible to write a script that will cast Midnight Pulse then ULT immideately after using blink dagger, right where Enigma is located?

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I have that script at home. Gonna upload after work. my script even includes dagger

Comment: @Wandang I'm genuinely curious. Do you manually include sleep() and action cancellation after midnight pulse ? Because IIRC the animation backswing or cast is pretty significant.

Comment: @T_O I never got **wait** (did not know about sleep but i guess it is the same? i am only using valves scripting commands, no lua, etc) to work. I instead used the onpress and onrelease events that valve provides to make it possible to manually cancel animation. It is not perfect but if practiced a bit it may help a lot.

Comment: @Wandang yea I'm not that familiar with Valve scripts in autoexec, but I'm sure something like wait or sleep exists. But your solution probably works and avoids animations

Answer (score 1):

Back from work

Midnight Pulse does indeed seem to be an annoyance. My old script did not feature that spell (instead bkb,dagger,ult)

The best i could do was this:

```
//Midnight Pulse then ULT immideately after using blink dagger
alias "sixLeftClick" "+sixense_left_click; -sixense_left_click"
alias "bkb" "dota_item_execute 0"
alias "pulse" "dota_ability_execute 2"
alias "ult" "dota_ability_execute 5"

alias "+enigcombo" "bkb; pulse; sixLeftClick"
alias "-enigcombo" "ult; sixLeftClick"
bind "b" "+enigcombo"
```

### Explaination:

The **sixense** is a feature Valve integrated to simulate mouse movement and clicks. We use this to simulate a leftclick at the position of the mouse cursor (this should met the criteria "at enigmas position" well enough)

**bkb**, **pulse** and **ult** should be self explanatory. They serve as an abbreviation for better reading. `dota_item_execute 0` needs to be adjusted (the number) to the itemslot that your bkb will be most of the time. The itemslots are formated like this:

```
0|1|2
3|4|5
```

**+enigcombo** does resemble a press down state (not releasing the button right away) while **-enigcombo** resembles a release of the button. this enables us to circumvent some valve limitations of just binding without those states.

Finally we bind any key (in this case **b**) to the button down state. Pressing b down results in executing bkb and the pulse at the position of the mouse cursor and releasing b results in executing ultimate at the position of the mouse cursor.

Here a quick demonstration I made to visualize this script.

The popups **button_up** and **button_down** have been added to show the minimal time **b** needs to be hold down.

### Problems

This script has a flaw. If you press and release b fast (like you normally would) pulse will not be executed. If you however hold down b for a short time the whole combo will be executed. You should try this script in practice mode to get a feel for it.

### Future

I am trying to tune this weakness by using shifting up to the point of pulse and then switching to manual commands again to cancel the pulse animation as fast as possible.

Comment: The point after which you can cancel the pulse is 300 milliseconds after cast, if that helps.

Comment: Where did you get that information if I might ask? Did you open the game files and looked up the casting time? If I ever be able to script timed commands I can use that info, thanks

Comment: I knew it offhand, but you can see it on any of the wikis under Cast Duration/Cast Point (0.3). There's also [this site](http://www.devilesk.com/dota2/castpoints) which covers each spell in the event that a certain spell has a modified cast point (ES ult, Furion TP, Zeus chain lightning, etc.) but may not be perfectly up to date.